# Why is expressjs returning the error "Cannot GET /" in the browser from code below?

Tags: node.js, express, get

Using the code below with nodejs, expressjs, socket io and pug

the browser response is Cannot GET /

Have had same or similar response to get in other code

Have index.pug file in root and views (just in case)

Tried various permutations such as "/", "./", "/views", "/views" etc

```
const express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','pug')

app.get("./", function(req, res){
res.render("home");
})

const runServer = app.listen(8585, ()=> console.log('server is running at 1 27.0.0.1:8585'))
```

Server runs at localhost:8585 in terminal (GIT bash) OK

Expected result: "Home" page in browser

Actual result: the browser when "./" response is Cannot GET /

If using "/" (vs "./") then terminal and browser either crash or respond with blank

Comment: Use `app.get("/", function(req, res){` and Let us know what error your facing

Comment: remove . from route /

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a route for GET / set?

```
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('app successfully running.')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering 'home' then why do you have `index.pug` inside views. You should have `home.pug` inside views folder. I tried the below code and it worked.

Folder structure:
- server.js
- views/home.pug

Code -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','pug')

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("home");
})

const runServer = app.listen(8585, ()=> console.log('server is running at 1 27.0.0.1:8585'))
```